# In Access 2007, how do I change the Auto Increment value?

Tags: ms-access-2007

Somehow, my table messed up the Auto Increment value and it's giving me a duplicate key on insert with auto-increment ID.  How do I set the Auto-Increment value in Access 2007?

Comment: Yes, it is.  It still somehow messed up.  It's crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure it out:

```
ALTER TABLE Table ALTER COLUMN Field COUNTER(1000,1)
```