# Increment a number by 4, starting with a number I choose

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

Is it possible, if one does not want to take the AutoValue, to take as default value for a Large Integer, or even normal number, the largest value already used for this from the column and add to it?

I need an increment of 4, starting with a number I choose.

I'm using version 2016 of Office.

I found several possible solutions, which I've entered into the expression generator of the default value at Field Properties:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL

=Max([MyID])+1
```

Or

```
CODE: SELECT ALL

=DomMax("MyID"; "Table name")
```

I always get the error message:

> Unknown function 'DMax' in the validity expression or default value in 'MyID.TableName'

I came across the tip that the references under VBA Editor --> Extras --> References must be correct. Here, however, I haven't the slightest idea which of these I would have to activate, if this is the problem at all.

Comment: Is this for a table or a form? By the way, the separator for the DMax function is a coma, not a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The PrimaryKey of a table can sometimes be used as a part number in a Parts table or a userID in a Users table but otherwise is a number the user of a database should never see and certainly not manipulate. This is the first reason I suggest solution 2.

Solution 1.  In Access just like with any other database I have seen that uses SQL, You can create an AutoNumber that increments by 4 using the Data Definition Language part of SQL.  Maybe the Access designers considered changing the increment too rare or too advanced to put in the menu system.  However, Altering the increment is not hard just open the query designer and go to the sql tab and type in appropriate SQL.

[In Access 2007, how do I change the Auto Increment value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738710/in-access-2007-how-do-i-change-the-auto-increment-value/16739016)

```
 First, Create your table as normal but don't insert any data.  Then open the query designer, and open the sql pane (In this case it doesn't matter what you have in the design view as you are over writing any SQL), type
```

```
ALTER TABLE MyTableName
ALTER COLUMN MyAutoNumberColumnName AUTOINCREMENT(1,4);
```

The sql pane's ribbon should auto select Data Definition Language.

Run the query and solution 1 is done.  When you enter Data in the table MyAutoNumberColumnName will start at 1 and increment by 4.

[image]

Solution 2:  Don't use the primary key.  Instead create another variable and display it.  This is one example why data should be entered using forms.  In the form's BeforeInsert Event calculate the variable and set it's textbox.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Me.txtBoxAlternateIDColumn.Value = Nz(DMax("MyAlternateIDColumn", "MyTableName") + 4, 1)
End Sub

'NZ handles the annoying case where the table is completely empty
```

I've used Solution 2 a couple times and I don't let the person doing data entry even see the alternateID textbox on the data entry form.

You can also use a Create Table statement in the DDL

Here is a youtube example of solution 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOg4P6v5ewA